# Android Re-loading a particular part of the Screen

Tags: android, android-framelayout, slidingmenu

I have a `FrameLayout` which has two components -

1. `Menu Panel` - Just like Facebook menu.
2. `Sliding Panel` - This consists of a `fixed header` + a `variable view` .

The Sliding panel has a fixed header and VARIABLE VIEW. 
The Variable view will change based on the item selected on the MENU Panel.

How to vary a particular view / how to reload a particular view with new contents?

Comment: can you please explain more what do you mean by variable view? do you use different layout on different case?

Comment: @Milanix : Yes the Views are kept in different xml files.

Comment: You can create one class for each xml, it can have it's own OnClickListeners. You can also create a public getView() method, and then you can use addView() method in your fragment/activity to dynamically switch views and still have OnClickListener attached to each of it. If you want I can include code for it.

Comment: @ Milanix : I tried creating class for each XML and included the click listeners as well. I will update in some time  if this works for me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `Fragments` for the variable view .
After reading about fragments here - http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 1):

1.Put the variable view in separate layout (i named as Layout2).

2.Remove all views in the Layout2.

3.Add views in Layout2 dynamically depends on the item selected.

Comment: If the Variable view has lot of sub views like - TextView , Buttons and all . How can we handle the click events and other events?

Comment: Use TableLayout. Add controls in TableRow. Then You can easily handle the click events.